# Open WhatsApp chat window to a specific number without passing a message using kotlin

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, message, whatsapp

I need to open the WhatsApp chat window to a specific number without passing a message in the intent

I tried to remove the `sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, userText)` but didn't help, when I send from the app it says

> "Can't send empty message"

Here is the complete code

```
    val sendIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN")
    sendIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
    sendIntent.type = "text/plain"
    sendIntent.putExtra("jid", number + "@s.whatsapp.net")
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, userText)
    startActivity(sendIntent)
```

Comment: This link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277585/want-to-open-whatsapp-to-chat-with-a-unsaved-contact-number-in-android-app 
and this https://medium.com/@mujtahidah/send-whatsapp-to-specific-number-android-studio-96c8caf7422f

Answer (score 3):

You can use WhatsApp uri to open a specific whatsapp chat without using any message like this. Here `num` can be any valid number including country code like *911234567890*

```
private fun openWhatsApp(num: String) {
    val isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp")
    if (isAppInstalled) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$num"))
        startActivity(intent)
    } else {
        // WhatsApp not installed show toast or dialog
    }
}
```

To check if WhatsApp is installed you can use this method

```
 private fun appInstalledOrNot(uri: String): Boolean {
    val pm = requireActivity().packageManager
    return try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
        true
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        false
    }
}
```